# JQuery $.noConflict(); is preventing my popup from working

Tags: jquery

I had a problem with a jQuery date-picker not working. Turns out I needed to add $.noConflict(); to make it work.

But now it has fixed one problem and started a new one.

None of my pop-ups are working. If I delete the $.noConflict(); they work perfectly fine, but then the date-picker stops.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
  $(function(){
    $.noConflict();
        $("#input-74567 > input").datepicker();
});
</script>
```

My input field ID for the datepicker is #input-74567.

Any ideas on a workaround for the "$.noConflict()" or any way to fix this problem?

Thanks...

Comment: Sounds like you are importing jQuery multiple times. It's not clear where but you should find it in your project and ensure you only import jQuery once.

Comment: You're not using it correctly.  When you call `.noConflict` the `$` variable is released.  See https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/  You would normally do something like `$myj = $.noConfilct()` `$myj("#id").hide()`

Comment: Or put the `.datepicker()` line before the `.noConflict`

Comment: @freedomn-m if `$.noConflict()` makes *something* work then that code is expecting a different `$`. I'm making an educated guess here that there is a second instance of jQuery and both are trying to control `$`. The correct approach is to try and fix that conflict before jumping onto `$.noConflict()` itself.

Comment: @VLAZ unfortunately I can only add code to the header (which is where I added the script above). I can't touch anything else. So if it is importing jQuery anywhere else, I can't change it. I need another workaround...

Comment: @VLAZ yes I believe you are 100% correct. But because of the platform I'm using, I can only make changes to the script above :(

Comment: @VLAZ agreed and already upvoted your comment; didn't see the need to re-iterate it, apologies if my comment sounds like I was disagreeing with fixing the source.